# Restrict the movement of subview inside superview bounds

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview

I have a UIView which is my VC's view(self.view) inside which I have another UIView added as subview both looks like a square. I would like to limit the movement of subview inside the superview. Basically the subview should not go outside the superview bounds.
I did implement

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event { 
// i check if point of touch is inside my superview i set the center i.e
UITouch *touch = [[UITouch allObjects] firstObject];
if (CGRectContainsPoint(subview.frame, [touch locationInView:self.view])) {
// set the center here... i.e
subview.center = [touch locationInView:self.view];
}
```

This works and subview is moving but it also moves outside the superview; how can I restrict the movement within the superview only?

I even tried something like .

```
if (CGRectContainsRect(self.view.bounds, subview.frame)) {
// this condition works but i don't know why my subview sticks to the sides of superview if i try to drag it through the bounds of superview
}
```

I don't do anything in touchesBegan, touchesCancelled, and nothing relevant in touchesEnd as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to check the "new frame" of the view you are moving, and compare its edges to the bounds of its superview:

```
@implementation DraggableView

- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    // restrict to superview bounds
    CGRect parentFrame = [self.superview bounds];
    
    UITouch *aTouch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [aTouch locationInView:self];
    CGPoint previousLocation = [aTouch previousLocationInView:self];
    
    // new frame for this "draggable" subview, based on touch offset when moving
    CGRect newFrame = CGRectOffset(self.frame, (location.x - previousLocation.x), (location.y - previousLocation.y));
    
    if (newFrame.origin.x < 0) {

        // if the new left edge would be outside the superview (dragging left),
        // set the new origin.x to Zero
        newFrame.origin.x = 0;
        
    } else if (newFrame.origin.x + newFrame.size.width > parentFrame.size.width) {
        
        // if the right edge would be outside the superview (dragging right),
        // set the new origin.x to the width of the superview - the width of this view
        newFrame.origin.x = parentFrame.size.width - self.frame.size.width;
        
    }
    
    if (newFrame.origin.y < 0) {

        // if the new top edge would be outside the superview (dragging up),
        // set the new origin.y to Zero
        newFrame.origin.y = 0;
        
    } else if (newFrame.origin.y + newFrame.size.height > parentFrame.size.height) {
        
        // if the new bottom edge would be outside the superview (dragging down),
        // set the new origin.y to the height of the superview - the height of this view
        newFrame.origin.y = parentFrame.size.height - self.frame.size.height;
        
    }
    
    // update this view's frame
    self.frame = newFrame;
}

@end
```

This also uses the offset of the touch, instead of centering the view on the touch (so it doesn't "jump to your finger" when you start dragging).

**Edit for clarification:** In this image, the Blue view class is `DraggableView`... It cannot be dragged outside of its superView (the Red view).

[image]

---

**Edit**

Swift version, with example view controller:

```
class DraggableView: UIView {
    
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        
        // unwrap superview and touch
        guard let sv = superview,
            let touch = touches.first
        else { return }
        
        let parentFrame = sv.bounds
        
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        let previousLocation = touch.previousLocation(in: self)
        
        // new frame for this "draggable" subview, based on touch offset when moving
        var newFrame = self.frame.offsetBy(dx: location.x - previousLocation.x, dy: location.y - previousLocation.y)
        
        // make sure Left edge is not past Left edge of superview
        newFrame.origin.x = max(newFrame.origin.x, 0.0)
        // make sure Right edge is not past Right edge of superview
        newFrame.origin.x = min(newFrame.origin.x, parentFrame.size.width - newFrame.size.width)

        // make sure Top edge is not past Top edge of superview
        newFrame.origin.y = max(newFrame.origin.y, 0.0)
        // make sure Bottom edge is not past Bottom edge of superview
        newFrame.origin.y = min(newFrame.origin.y, parentFrame.size.height - newFrame.size.height)
        
        self.frame = newFrame
        
    }

}
class DraggableTestViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let dragView = DraggableView()
        dragView.backgroundColor = .cyan
        dragView.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 50, height: 50)
        
        let containerView = UIView()
        containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        containerView.backgroundColor = .red
        
        containerView.addSubview(dragView)
        
        view.addSubview(containerView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            containerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300.0),
            containerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.widthAnchor),
            containerView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            containerView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor),
        ])

    }
    
}
```

Comment: Bingo @DonMag :)..... 1 clarification though, was it just due to this touch offset that my solution was not working ??

Comment: There is 1 problem that i see here, when i drag along my superview then also subview is getting dragged i guesss because touchesBegan is working for it(superview) as well. how can i avoid this??

Comment: @user2606782 - not quite sure what you're asking... See the edit with screen-cap in my answer - maybe that will help?

Comment: actually my draggable view isn't a separate class and hence touchesMoved is getting called for both superView and it's subView. i hope you understand. Any way to avoid this? other then creating a separate draggableView class for subView??

Comment: any pointer on if what i asked earlier can be achieved without making separate draggableView class??

Comment: any reason you don't want it to be a subclassed view?

Comment: I need to find Swift version this answer. Could you please help me? @DonMag

Comment: @EmreDeğirmenci - see **Edit** at bottom of my answer.