# Move an UIView in a limited area of the screen using pan gesture

Tags: ios, swift, uipangesturerecognizer

In my application, there is an UIView which should be moved in y direction when user pans in y direction on the super view within the given boundaries.

**This is how it should work**

[image]

**This is my code**

```
@IBOutlet weak var uiview: UIView!
// self.view is the supper view of uiview

var uiviewLastCenterPosition = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
var lastTranslation = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.uiviewLastCenterPosition = self.uiview.center
}

@IBAction func supperViewPan(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    switch sender.state {

    case .began:
        break
    case .changed:

        let uiviewTop = self.uiview.frame.origin.y
        let uiviewBottom = self.uiview.frame.origin.y + self.uiview.frame.size.height

        let velocity = sender.velocity(in: self.view)

        if velocity.y > 0.0 { // down

            if uiviewBottom < 600{

                self.uiview.center.y = (self.uiviewLastCenterPosition.y) + sender.translation(in: self.view).y
                self.lastTranslation = sender.translation(in: self.view)
            }else{
                sender.setTranslation(self.lastTranslation, in: self.view)
            }

        }else if velocity.y < 0.0 { // up

            if uiviewTop > 100{

                self.uiview.center.y = (self.uiviewLastCenterPosition.y) + sender.translation(in: self.view).y
                self.lastTranslation = sender.translation(in: self.view)
            }else{
                sender.setTranslation(self.lastTranslation, in: self.view)
            }
        }
        break

    case .ended:

        self.uiviewLastCenterPosition = self.uiview.center
        break

    default:
        break
    }
}
```

All works perfect when user pans slowly. But when user pans fast, uiview goes beyond the boundaries.

[image]        [image]

Can someone please help me on this. I want to move the view exactly inside those boundaries. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: instead of velocity you have to put condition on the moving view position.

Comment: @dahiya_boy I have already put two conditions on the moving view position.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Restrict the movement of subview inside superview bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47413817/restrict-the-movement-of-subview-inside-superview-bounds)

Comment: @GMHSJ did you find any solution on this?? having same issue. Please post your answer if you solved it

Comment: @Bhavik Yes I was able to do it. Will post it as the answer ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

You should clip the position before changing the position of the view which is `self.uiview.center.y` in your case. Look for the changes in the code.

```
@IBAction func supperViewPan(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    switch sender.state {
    case .changed:
        let viewTop = self.slideView.frame.origin.y
        let viewBottom = self.slideView.frame.origin.y + self.slideView.frame.size.height
        let halfHeight = self.slideView.frame.height / 2 // here
        let velocity = sender.velocity(in: self.view)
        if velocity.y > 0.0 { // down
            if viewBottom < 600 {
                var displacedPosition = (self.uiviewLastCenterPosition.y) + sender.translation(in: self.view).y
                // changes here
                displacedPosition = displacedPosition > 600 - halfHeight ? 600 - halfHeight : displacedPosition 
                displacedPosition = displacedPosition < 100 + halfHeight ? 100 + halfHeight : displacedPosition 
                self.slideView.center.y = displacedPosition
                self.lastTranslation = sender.translation(in: self.view)
            } else {
                sender.setTranslation(self.lastTranslation, in: self.view)
            }
        } else if velocity.y < 0.0 { // up
            if viewTop > 100 {
                var displacedPosition = (self.uiviewLastCenterPosition.y) + sender.translation(in: self.view).y
                // changes here
                displacedPosition = displacedPosition < 100 + halfHeight ? 100 + halfHeight : displacedPosition
                displacedPosition = displacedPosition > 600 - halfHeight ? 600 - halfHeight : displacedPosition 
                self.slideView.center.y = displacedPosition
                self.lastTranslation = sender.translation(in: self.view)
            } else {
                sender.setTranslation(self.lastTranslation, in: self.view)
            }
        }
        break
    case .ended:
        self.uiviewLastCenterPosition = self.slideView.center
        break
    default:
        break
    }
}
```