# How to set boundaries of dragging control using UIPanGestureRecognizer?

Tags: ios, swift, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a View, inside that I am adding a Label then I tried to set boundary for moving Label using PanGesture. Below is my code:

```
@objc func handlePan(_ gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    if gestureRecognizer.state == .began || gestureRecognizer.state == .changed {
        let translation = gestureRecognizer.translation(in: self)
        if let view = gestureRecognizer.view {

            if (view.frame.origin.x + translation.x >= 0) && (view.frame.origin.y + translation.y >= 0) && (view.frame.origin.x + translation.x <= view.frame.width) && (view.frame.origin.y + translation.y <= view.frame.height)
            {
                view.center = CGPoint(x:view.center.x + translation.x,
                                       y:view.center.y + translation.y)
            }
        }
        gestureRecognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self)
    }

}
```

I took the reference of this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/49008808/9970928

But it does not work, can anyone tell what I am missing in the condition?

Comment: @dahiya_boy yes I am setting up the boundary of main view, here the view is UILabel which I have added in my main view. Now the label should not be go beyond main view.

Comment: Instead of view you have to set boundary on label.

Comment: No, @dahiya_boy here view is label. So I think there should be some logic to check main view boundary.

Comment: You need to read your code properly and have to debug, bcz you dont know what you are doing. You just copied and paste the code.

Comment: @dahiya_boy worked below solution. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is not most intuitive but assuming everything else works the problem is that it only goes off the bounds on right and bottom. Look at your condition with:

```
(view.frame.origin.x + translation.x <= view.frame.width)
(view.frame.origin.y + translation.y <= view.frame.height)
```

So it says that the origin may not be greater than size of bounds what you want to do is check the maximum values of the inner view:

```
(view.frame.maxX + translation.x <= view.frame.width)
(view.frame.maxY + translation.y <= view.frame.height)
```

But this procedure in general may produce issues. Imagine that user swipes very quickly rightwards. And that the maximum `center.x` could be `100`. Current `center.x` is `50` and user drags it in a single frame to `200`. Your condition will fail and your label will stay at `50` instead of `100`. I would go with clamping the frame to bounds.

Something like the following should do:

```
func clampFrame(_ frame: CGRect, inBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    let center: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: max(bounds.minX + frame.width*0.5, min(frame.midX, bounds.maxX - frame.width*0.5)),
                                  y: max(bounds.minY + frame.height*0.5, min(frame.midY, bounds.maxY - frame.height*0.5)))
    return CGRect(x: center.x-frame.width*0.5, y: center.y-frame.height*0.5, width: frame.width, height: frame.height)
}

func moveFrame(_ frame: CGRect, by translation: CGPoint, constrainedTo bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    var newFrame = frame
    newFrame.origin.x += translation.x
    newFrame.origin.y += translation.y
    return clampFrame(newFrame, inBounds: bounds)
}
```

There may be other issues as well using "translation" procedure. I would go with finding a location in view. Please see the following working example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let myView = MyView(frame: CGRect(x: 100.0, y: 100.0, width: 200.0, height: 200.0))
        myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        view.addSubview(myView)
        let label = UILabel(frame: .zero)
        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue.withAlphaComponent(0.2)
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 50.0)
        label.text = "Hi!"
        label.sizeToFit()
        myView.addSubview(label)
        label.addGestureRecognizer(UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: myView, action: #selector(MyView.handlePan)))
        label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }


}

class MyView: UIView {

    func clampFrame(_ frame: CGRect, inBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        let center: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: max(bounds.minX + frame.width*0.5, min(frame.midX, bounds.maxX - frame.width*0.5)),
                                      y: max(bounds.minY + frame.height*0.5, min(frame.midY, bounds.maxY - frame.height*0.5)))
        return CGRect(x: center.x-frame.width*0.5, y: center.y-frame.height*0.5, width: frame.width, height: frame.height)
    }

    func moveFrame(_ frame: CGRect, by translation: CGPoint, constrainedTo bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        var newFrame = frame
        newFrame.origin.x += translation.x
        newFrame.origin.y += translation.y
        return clampFrame(newFrame, inBounds: bounds)
    }

    private var startLocation: CGPoint = .zero
    private var startFrame: CGRect = .zero

    @objc func handlePan(_ gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        guard let label = gestureRecognizer.view else { return }

        if gestureRecognizer.state == .began {
            startLocation = gestureRecognizer.location(in: self)
            startFrame = label.frame
        } else if gestureRecognizer.state == .changed {
            let newLocation = gestureRecognizer.location(in: self)
            let translation = CGPoint(x: newLocation.x-startLocation.x, y: newLocation.y-startLocation.y)

            label.frame = moveFrame(startFrame, by: translation, constrainedTo: self.bounds)
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Wow!! Matic, its great solution..It improved my panning also. Thanks a lot!